# Varying Results When Displaying Result Matrix

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I am currently working on a code that calculates the following equation:
W = (XT * X)^-1 * XT * Y
with XT being the transpose of X and ^-1 the inverse of the product XT*X.

To do this, I am passing a text file with a matrix to the program, and then performing operations on it to obtain the proper matrix formats to use in the equation.  Although the code works some times, there are instances when I will run the code and receive the proper answer, but others when a random number will be produced.

For example, when using the matrix [first integer = columns-1, second integer = rows]:

```
4 
4
4.000000,3.000000,2.000000,3.000000,200.000000
5.000000,2.000000,1.000000,7.000000,300.000000
1.000000,4.000000,2.000000,1.000000,500.000000
8.000000,8.000000,9.000000,3.000000,200.000000
```

it will produce an answer for XT * (XT * X)^-1 as:

```
0.497617        -0.166646       0.061712        -0.137570
-61.086998      -0.258283       -0.340935       -0.064228
0.186411        -0.083895       0.285920        -0.082587
-0.722773       0.207515        -0.009408       0.238550
-0.579552       0.345476        0.154362        0.055048
```

and the numbers will not remain the same through each test run.  It does this with this result matrix multiplied by Y [the last column in the original matrix] as well.  Below is a sample of the code I have written thus far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
if(argc < 2){
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        FILE *fptrain = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        int row, col, i, j;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &col);
        col = col+1;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &row);
        char ch;

        //creates the original X and Y matrix
        float trainX[row][col];
        float trainY[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                trainX[i][0] = 1.000000;
                for(j=1; j<col; j++)
                {
                        fscanf(fptrain, "%f%c", &trainX[i][j], &ch);
                }

                        fscanf(fptrain, "%f%c", &trainY[i][0], &ch);
        }
 //creates the X transposed matrix
        float trainXtrans[col][row];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                        trainXtrans[j][i] = trainX[i][j];
                }
        }

        //multiplies X and X transposed
        float trainXtemp[row][row];
        int s;
        int num=0;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        for(s=0; s<col; s++)
                        {
                                num = num + trainX[i][s]*trainXtrans[s][j];
                        }
                                trainXtemp[i][j] = num;
                                num =0;
                }
        }
 //finds the identity matrix of X times X transposed
        float trainXinden[row][row*2];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        trainXinden[i][j] = trainXtemp[i][j];
                }
                for(j=row; j<row*2; j++)
                {
                        if(j==i+row)
                        {
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
 //finds the inverse of X times X transposed through Gauss Jordan Elimination
        int k;
        float divscalar;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                divscalar = trainXinden[i][i];
                for(j=0; j<row*2; j++)
                {
                        trainXinden[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j]/divscalar;
                }
                for(k=0; k<row; k++)
                {
                        if(i!=k)
                        {
                                float subscalar = trainXinden[k][i];
                                for(j=0; j<row*2; j++)
                                {
                                        trainXinden[k][j] = trainXinden[k][j] - subscalar*trainXinden[i][j];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
 //copies over the result of gauss jordan elimination
        float trainXinverse[row][row];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        trainXinverse[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j+row];
                }
        }
 //multiplies (X times X transpose) inverse by (X transposed)
        float trainXinvXt[col][row];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)
                {
                        for(s=0; s<row; s++)
                        {
                                trainXinvXt[i][j] += trainXtrans[i][s]*trainXinverse[s][j];
                        }
                }
        }
        //multiples (trainXinvXt) by Y
        float weight[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(s=0; s<col-1; s++)
                {
                        weight[i][0] += trainXinvXt[i][s]*trainY[s][0];
                }

        }
return 0;
}
```

is this perhaps a memory issue or is my Gauss-Jordan Elimination method throwing something off?

Comment: I'm not sure where you came up with the code for the gauss-jordan elimination, however, the gauss-jordan elimination solves the linear system of equations itself without additional need for separate transpose or identity formation. You may want to visit [C Program to Implement Gauss Jordan Elimination Method](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-implement-gauss-jordan-elimination/). The `solution` function is a gauss-jornan elimination. (the rest of the code is sub-par, but `solution` is fine)

Comment: The assignment requires us to use the identity form to solve with Gauss-Jordan.